# Can I update directly from Ubuntu 9.10 to 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, 9.10

I was using Ubuntu 9.10 version and today I want to upgrade to 10.10.

I updated my ubuntu 9.10 with this commands:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop 
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade 
update-manager -d
```

But when I opened update manager I couldn't see button for upgrading to 10.10 (or 10.04) will be available.

How can I upgrade now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System->Administration->**Software Sources**, go to the tab **Updates**, set the **Release upgrade** to **Normal releases** then restart the Update Manager, that should solve the problem.

You can't upgrade to 10.10 directly, you'll have to upgrade to 10.04 and then upgrade to 10.10.

Answer (score 5):

No, upgrade is only possible to the immediately following release except in the case of a LTS release, when direct upgrade from one LTS to the following is allowed. You have to first upgrade to 10.04 and then to 10.10.

The command `update-manager -d` is used for upgrading to a development version. Since both 10.04 and 10.10 have been released to public, you cannot upgrade to either of them using that command.

Your update-manager must be showing the button for upgrading to 10.04 when you start it normally(ie without the "-d" option). If you don't want to reinstall then use that button to upgrade to 10.04 version first and then upgrade to maverick in the same way.

Comment: Well...it's *possible*.  It's just a really bad idea.

Comment: Firstly upgrading 10.04 then 10.10 took hours. It was really bad idea :/

Comment: Three release-upgrades in three consecutive days took me to karmic from hardy, but I used crontab to download the packages during night.

Answer (score 0):

i would advise that you download ubuntu 10.10 , burn it to a CD and then run it. (BUT BACK UP ALL OF YOUR DATA FIRST)

Comment: I know, it is the best way, but I have both windows 7 and Ubuntu operating systems on my PC. I was afraid of erase windows 7 during insallation.